# Delay emitted observable values depending on the value of another observable

Tags: redux, rxjs, ngrx

I am using `forkJoin` to wait for the completion of 4 observables. With the last emitted values from each, I use `switchMap` to trigger some NgRx actions (`ConfiguratorLoaded`, `GetProjectMembers`, `SwitchOrganization`):

```
forkJoin(
    this.projectsService.getProject(action.projectId),
    this.flavors$,
    this.images$,
    this.storageDefinitions$
).pipe(
    switchMap(([project, flavors, images, storageDefinitions]) => [
        new ConfiguratorLoaded(
            flavors,
            images,
            storageDefinitions,
            project
        ),
        new GetProjectMembers(action.projectId),
        new SwitchOrganization(
            this.getOrganizationById(project.organizationId)
        ),
    ])
);
```

I have another observable `loaded$` which is of type `Observable<boolean>`and not in the code example above.
**How can I get the 3 NgRx actions to be triggered when `loaded$` has the value `true` and not before?** As long as `loaded$` has the value `false`, the actions should not be triggered. So it's kind of a pause.

Comment: `loaded$.pipe(mergeMap(() => forkJoin(....)))`

Comment: No, I'm afraid it doesn't work that way. What I want to achieve is to "pause" the triggering of the actions in `switchMap()` until `loaded$` takes the value `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to do this:

```
combineLatest([
    this.loaded$,
    this.projectsService.getProject(action.projectId),
    this.flavors$,
    this.images$,
    this.storageDefinitions$
]).pipe(
   filter(([loaded]) => Boolean(loaded)),
   // ...
)
```

The combineLatest will re-emit each time the `this.loaded$` stream emits.

If `this.loaded$` emits false, the filter will skip processing the `switchMap`.

If `this.loaded$` emits true, the filter will continue and process the `switchMap`.

This then effectively "waits" until `this.loaded$` is true before it executes your NgRx actions.

Comment:  Just what I was looking for. Thank you very much!